# How to copy more than one field of structure to another?

Tags: c

I am learning structure and its operation i which how can i copy specific fields of structure to another ?

example

```
struct student
{
  int rollno;
  int standard;
  char name[50];
  char add[100];
  int marks;
};

struct studentmarks
{
    int rollno;
    char name[50];
    int marks;
};
```

how can i copy **rollno,name,marks** field from above structure into below ?
i have already tried ***memcpy*** but it copies entire structure i just want to copy only specific fields from above structure is there any simple way to do it ?
thanks for the help!!!

Comment: `memcpy(b.rollno,a.rollno,sizeof(int));` `a` is an object of type `struct student` and `b` is an object of type `struct studentmarks` other way is `b.rollno = a.rollno;`

Comment: `b.rollno = a.rollno;`

Comment: Using `memcpy` tricks is a pretty sure way to shoot yourself in the leg. You add one member to the struct and hello - all assignment code should be rewritten. Create an assignment function and use it.

Comment: Duplication of information is a probable symptom of something wrong. You probably should use pointers instead (perhaps have a `struct student* pstud;` field in `struct studentmarks`)

Comment: @Gopi: Any reason to use the unsafe `memcpy` instead of a simple, typesafe assignment?

Answer (score 6):

Write a function that does that for you:

```
void copy_some_fields(studentmarks* dst, const student* src)
{
    assert(dst != NULL);
    assert(src != NULL);

    dst->rollno = src->rollno;
    dst->marks = src->marks;
    strcpy(dst->name, src->name);
}
```

You can use it as follows:

```
int main()
{
    student src; 
    // initialize src...

    studentmarks dst; 
    // initialize dst...

    copy_some_fields(&dst, &src);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C supports direct copy of `struct` of the same type, such as `s2 = s1` (given both `s1, s2` are of type `struct student`).

You can't do *partial copy* of structs, though. So for your task, you would need to copy field-by-field, such as:

```
studentmarks.rollno = student.rollno;
```